# Entropy for logistic distribution

Tags: math, entropy

According to Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution, the entropy of a logistic distribution is ln(s) + 2, where s > 0 is the scale parameter.

However, ln(s) + 2 with s > 0 can result a negative entropy value, such as,

```
>>> s = 0.1
>>> print (math.log(s) + 2)
-0.30258509299404546
```

I am confused here. How could an entropy be negative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After checking "[A Mathematical Theory of Communication](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf)" , I found that "The entropy of a continuous distribution can be negative.". As the logistic distribution is a continuous distribution, the entropy can be negative.

There are three main categories to classify communication systems: discrete, continuous and mixed.

1. **discrete**: a sequence of choices from a finite set. We can think this
   is the discrete variable in statistics.
2. **continuous**: "A continuous
       system is one in which the message and signal are both treated as
       continuous functions, e.g., radio or television". We can think this
       is the continuous variable which has an infinite number of values in
       statistics.
3. **mixed**: discrete + continuous

The definition/equation of "entropy" for discrete set of probabilities and a continuous distribution are different ("20. ENTROPY OF A CONTINUOUS DISTRIBUTION" in the paper). I only knew entropy for discrete variables before. Now, it is clear for me.